# Is there a way to enable Netflix's 5.1 channel audio in on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, netflix, 5.1

Apparently, Netflix's 5.1 audio does not work via Silverlight or HTML5, only way to officially get 5.1 on a PC is via Windows 8 app.

Is there a way to enable this on Windows 7?

Comment: This question is not on topic.  Questions about Netflix are not on topic here at Superuser.  You have answered your own question, the only way to get 5.1 Audio, is to use the Netflix Application on the Windows Store.  *Windows 7 cannot use any program from the Windows Store.*  So the only way to get 5.1 audio on a PC running Windows is to upgrade to Windows 8.1 or Windows 10.